# Windows got crashed and how to recover the old Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, dbf

unexpected Crash of windows took place. I dont have a metadata backup. After reinstalling windows i have taken the old database folder back up which has all

- system01.dbf
- sysaux01.dbf
- undotbs01.dbf
- Temp01.dbf
- users01.dbf
- redo01.log
- redo02.log
- redo03.log

[image]

Please share your recommendations to go forward.

Comment: first start by installing oracle

Answer (score 1):

Easiest option is to install Oracle with the same version as the old one, create a database with the exact same name as the old one and at the exact same location as the old one. 
Once you have that working, shut down the database. Then copy your backup files over the new files. Start the database.